# Why can I call a method on a class without instantiating it?

Tags: java, integer, static-methods

For example, I call a method from Integer, like `toHexString()`.

Now I need to print it out by the following code.

```
    int i = 123455;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(i));
```

I haven't created a new object named `Integer`. Why I can use `Integer`, this object, directly?

Comment: `Integer` is a *class*, not an *object*.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be able to call this `static` method?

Answer (score 8):

You can use it like that, because `toHexString` is a `static` method.

For `static` members, you don't need an instance, you can call them directly through the class.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now

Answer (score 3):

`Integer.toHexString(i)` - calls static method of class Integer. `Static methods` don't demand object to be created.

You can read more in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 2):

Its just because `toHexString` is a `static` method so You can access it in three ways.

### First Way

`Integer.toHexString(i); //static method directly access using Class Name .`

### Second Way

```
Integer v_objInt = null;
    v_objInt.toHexString(i);   //this will also work.
```

> Option **B** will also work because `static`can also access by using any `null` **referenced** Class Object.

### Third way

```
Integer v_objInt = new Integer();
v_objInt.toHexString(i);   //this will also work.
```

> Option **C** will also work because `static`can also access by using any Initialized **referenced** Class Object.

Comment: Second and third way is not good way of accessing the method. because (I'm quoting the compiler warning) `The static method toHexString(int) from the type Integer should be accessed in a static way`

Comment: @nafas I am only suggesting the number of possible way that can use at this Scenario .

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `static` methods by referring to class name or using an object reference (that often leads to mistakes and misunderstanding). So I suggest not using the second way.

```
Integer.toHexString(i);

Integer i = new Integer(1);
i.toHexString(i);
```

---

In your case, `Integer` is just a class name (not an object as you noted) which has a `static` method called `toHexString(int i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding up to what everyone else has already said.

> There is an implicit import of java.lang.*.

`Integer` is one of the class in that package. Thus this class does NOT require an `import`. This is why you can use this Class directly without creating your own Integer Class or importing it